# libvips / pyvips access small sections of a multi-channel tiff (OME-Tiff)

Tags: python, image-processing, tiff, vips

Wondering if there's a speedy way to return specific pixel ranges of a given channel of an ome-tiff file using pyvips / libvips. The `crop` doesn't allow for channel specfics.

My OME-Tiff is large (10 GB+) so I don't want to load the entire image into memory.

Open to any suggestions and/or other workflows.

Comment: You could lazy access the data as a [zarr](https://pypi.org/project/zarr/) array or group via [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/). E.g. `zarr.open(tifffile.imread('multi-channel-z-series.ome.tif', aszarr=True), mode='r')[1, 1:4, 32:64, 32:64]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyvips supports multipage documents as "toilet-roll" images (sorry). You set `n=-1` to load all the pages, and they appear as a very tall, thin image, with the pages stacked vertically. The metadata item `page-height` gives the height in pixels of each sheet.

Docs here:

https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/VipsForeignSave.html#vips-tiffload

For example:

```
$ vipsheader -a multi-channel-z-series.ome.tif 
multi-channel-z-series.ome.tif: 439x167 char, 1 band, b-w, tiffload
width: 439
height: 167
bands: 1
format: char
coding: none
interpretation: b-w
xoffset: 0
yoffset: 0
xres: 0
yres: 0
filename: multi-channel-z-series.ome.tif
vips-loader: tiffload
n-pages: 15
image-description: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!-- Warning: this comment is an OME-XML metadata block, which contains crucial dimensional parameters and other important metadata. Please edit cautiously (if at all), and back up the original data before doing so...
resolution-unit: cm
orientation: 1
```

You can see this is a 15 page OME image. pyvips will load page 0 by default, and each page is 439 by 167 pixels. You can fetch the XML in `image-description` to see the full OME channel metadata.

```
$ vipsheader -f image-description multi-channel-z-series.ome.tif
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--- ... etc.
```

In Python you can do:

```
$ python3
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyvips
>>> x = pyvips.Image.new_from_file("multi-channel-z-series.ome.tif", n=-1)
>>> x.size
>>> x.width
439
>>> x.height
2505
>>> x.get("page-height")
167
>>> x.height / x.get("page-height")
15.0
```

So you can use `crop` to fetch a rect from a channel in the obvious way.

Are you planning to generate patches for ML training? If you are, `fetch` can be much faster than `crop` for small patches. [This issue](https://github.com/libvips/pyvips/issues/100#issuecomment-493960943) has sample code and some benchmarks --- in that example, `crop` takes 41s to make 12,000 32x32 patches, but `fetch` takes just 0.5s.

Comment: Thanks John, Appreciate your ownership of the library. Quick question -- if i'm just trying to load the nth channel, can i just give `n=10` to load the 10th channel, or is it quicker to do `n=-1` and do the vertical offset math.

Comment: Nvm -- i see that n is the number of pages.

Comment: Use `page=10` to pull out just the 10th page, use `n=` to set the number of pages to fetch. Tiles are decompressed on demand, so it won't make much difference to runtime.